# Is dangerous to start threads in Java and not to wait for them (with .join())?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

When writing a multithread internet server in java, the main-thread starts new
ones to serve incoming requests in parallel.

Is any problem if the main-thread does not wait ( with `.join()`) for them?
(It is obviously absurd create a new thread and then, wait for it).

I know that, in a practical situation, you should (or "you must"?)  implement a pool
of threads to "re-use" them for new requests when they become idle.

But for small applications, should we use a pool of threads?

Comment: Threads are design to work as independently as possible.  They often work best this way.

Comment: 250KLOC of highly multi-threaded code here, adapting to the number of cores the computer has, etc.  We're not using *join* a single time.  Not once.  If you're using *join* you're probably doing it wrong: it's wwaayy too low-level.  Use higher-level concurrency abstraction.  Moreover *join* is deficient (it's an API flaw).  This is very nicely explained in the amazing *"Java Concurrency In Practice"* book (no, I'm not telling where: buy the book, use the index, and see for yourself what concurrency gurus have to say about it: to me their authoritative on the subject).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem in your approach is that it does not scale well beyond a certain request rate. If the requests are coming in faster than your server is able to handle them, the number of threads will rise continuously. As each thread adds some overhead and uses CPU time, the time for handling each request will get longer, so the problem will get worse (because the number of threads rises even faster). Eventually no request will be able to get handled anymore because all of the CPU time is wasted with overhead. Probably your application will crash.

The alternative is to use a ThreadPool with a fixed upper bound of threads (which depends on the power of the hardware). If there are more requests than the threads are able to handle, some requests will have to wait too long in the request queue, and will fail due to a timeout. But the application will still be able to handle the rest of the incoming requests.

Fortunately the Java API already provides a nice and flexible ThreadPool implementation, see [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Using this is probably even easier than implementing everything with your original approach, so no reason not to use it.

Comment: Yes I agree (you confirm my guess). But, consider this. Without using a pool of threads nor waiting for them with .join, you still can know when a thread ends (with two shared variables) and thus control how many threads are started at most.

Comment: The thread pool can control the maximum number of thread created.

Comment: @cibercitizen Of course you can do this (though you have to be careful about synchronization). But why duplicate work that was already implemented in the Java API?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to wait for threads.

They can either complete running on their own (if they've been spawned to perform one particular task), or run indefinitely (e.g. in a server-type environment).

They *should* handle interrupts and respond to shutdown requests, however. See [this article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) on how to do this correctly.

If you need a set of threads I would use a pool and [executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) methods since they'll look after thread resource management for you. If you're writing a multi-threaded network server then I would investigating using (say) a servlet container or a framework such as [Mina](http://mina.apache.org/).

Comment: So, Brian, I never need to write .join() nor use a pool threads?

Comment: I would use an existing pool/executor infrastructure if possible/necessary. See above for links.

Answer (score 1):

Thread.join() lets you wait for the Thread to end, which is mostly contrary to what you want when starting a new Thread. At all, you start the new thread to do stuff in parallel to the original Thread.

Only if you really need to wait for the spawned thread to finish, you should join() it.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for your threads if you need their results or need to do some cleanup which is only possible after all of them are dead, otherwise not.

For the Thread-Pool: I would use it whenever you have some non-fixed number of tasks to run, i.e. if the number depends on the input.

Comment: In the case of a internet server, the number of request to serve is obviously unbound. So, will you use a pool of threads as a general requirement? Or only to control the max. number of clients served in parallel?

Comment: In an HTTP or similar server, where normally the execution time of each task is limited, I certainly would use a thread pool, if only to avoid the overhead of Thread creation. (It is not a **general requirement**, but simply makes the application usually more performant, and adds a bit of configurability.)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to collect the main ideas of this interesting (for me) question.

1. I can't totally agree with "you
   don't need to wait for threads".
   Only in the sense that if you don't
   join a thread (and don't have a
   pointer to it) once the thread is
   done, its resources are freed
   (right? I'm not sure).
2. The use of a thread pool is only
   necessary to avoid the overhead of
   thread creation, because ...
3. You can limit the number of parallel
   *running* threads by accounting, with shared variables (and without a thread pool), how many of then
   were started  but not yet finished.